# ReactJS and NodeJS same server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server

I build a project with nodejs and react. I don't know if I must split in 2 servers, one for the react app and one for API in nodejs and the react app ask request at nodejs server.

Or I must group both in only one nodejs process ? What's the difference ? There are a better choice ?

Comment: React doesn't care what you use on the backend. It's just a view

Comment: Don't run the React development server in production! Build it, then serve the static files however you like.

Comment: It's really up to you, I don't think there is a canonical approach, or that one is better than the other.

Comment: @Jaxx The mono-server is generally used for its simplicity but when it comes to scaling your application you would rather scale differently your application back-end process from your static serving server. That's why it always end up separated. It will still works fine as a single server for application that's doesn't needs to scale tho.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you React when builded is just static files, don't get confused by the development server. I would recommend you for the beginning to put them in one node process. Just declare the folder of the static files like this:

```
app.use('/app', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/app')));
```

Also if you are using React Router you should add this as your last router

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
});
```

You can check my template repo with webpack [here](https://github.com/dimkirt/react-template)